# How can I assign the SpecialCells of one range to a new range?

Tags: excel, vba

I know that I can accomplish this via iterating over the first range, but I'm curious to see if I can accomplish it using the `SpecialCells` property.

Say I have a column of names with empty cells in between:

```
 A     B    C
Jon
Jim
Sally

Jane


Mary
```

If I want to use VBA to copy over just the used cells, I can say

```
Range("A1:A8").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Copy
Range("C1:C"&Range("A1:A8").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Count).PasteSpecial
```

and end up with

```
 A     B    C
Jon        Jon
Jim        Jim
Sally      Sally
           Jane    
Jane       Mary


Mary
```

Instead, I'd like to be able to do this without having to paste a range anywhere.

What I want to be able to do is have a range containing `[Jon,Jim,Sally,Jane,Mary]`, but if I try `Set rng = Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants,xlTextValues)`, I either end up with the spaces as elements of the range, or using a hard-coded range of cells, with one that counts only `[Jon, Jim, Sally]` before it hits the space.

I'd like to be able to use the range elsewhere in the code, and I think the SpecialCells is a nice compact way of doing it, but is my only alternative to do it in a loop and compare cells as `<> ""`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)

Debug.Print r.Rows.Count, r.Cells.Count
' returns:        3            5
```

The only reliable piece of information in the above is `r.Cells.Count`. The `Rows` get cut at the first blank. I imagine this confuses the whole pasting process. So, you can't paste `r` directly to the worksheet.

You could transfer it to a Variant array, and then slap* that onto the sheet. But how to do this? Well, `r.Cells` is akin to a collection. Perhaps convert it to an array like this:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim c As Range
Dim v As Variant
ReDim v(1 To r.Cells.Count, 1 To 1)
i = 0
For Each c In r
    i = i + 1
    v(i, 1) = c
Next c
Range("B1").Resize(UBound(v,1),UBound(v,2)) = v
```

No need to check for empty cells.

You could also use Chip Pearson's [`CollectionToArray` procedure](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CollectionsAndDictionaries.htm), which is basically a fancier implementation of the above code, maybe with a bit of modification.

By the way, checking for `<> ""` will not reject cells whose value is an empty string `""`. If you must check for truly empty/"blank" cells, then `IsEmpty` is safer.

<sub>*Credits to @Issun for coining "slap" in this context.</sub>

Comment: Are you sure about that last part? I have tested this, and if you do Range("A5").Value = "" before you check len(cell) <> 0, it will reject the cell.

Comment: Just for clarification, I am talking about len(text) <> 0. I agree that checking if <> "" is a horrible idea.

Comment: Why bother with the second dimension on v, just curious?

Comment: Habit, mostly, and convenience. If `v` is two-dimensional, then it will "paste" on the sheet as `v(row, col)`, matrix-style. If `v` is one-dimensional, then it will paste as `v(col)` i.e. horizontally along a row, vector-style. If you try to paste it in a vertical range, it won't work properly. Maybe there's a workaround to do this, I don't know...

Comment: +1 for the nice solution. Pasting by slapping the variant array is very convenient and I use it all the time (that and dictionaries).

Comment: "Slapping": I've been looking for a term for this when writing answers! Will have to remember "slapping"

Comment: Ahah - the most common term is acutally 'dumping' the elements into an array and 'dumping' the array back onto a range, but I like 'slapping' the array onto the file more :) I envision it like poker and you are hodling the hand (array) and slapping it back onto the table in one move.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to just use the specialcells, you'll need to do a for each loop, but here's how to do it without a variant array or checking for empty cell. Note that I am using a dictionary in reverse (see notes below) to store cells as items (not keys) so I can utilize the .Items method that spits out an array of all items in the dictionary.

```
Sub test()

Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

For Each cell In Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    dict.Add i, cell.Value
    i = i + 1
Next

Sheet1.Range("c1").Resize(dict.Count).Value = _
Application.Transpose(dict.items)

End Sub
```

But there is a faster way to do this, in case you are working with a fairly big range. Use the dictionary object since it has the ability to spit out an array of all the keys/items inside it (which you can transpose to a range). Collections do not have this abliity, but dictionaries only allow 1 of each key. The work around? Use the dictionary in reverse, placing your values as items and a counter for keys!

Here's an example of how to use the variant array/dictionary (with dupes allowed):

```vb
Sub test()

Dim vArray As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

vArray = Range("A1:A10").Value

For i = 1 To UBound(vArray, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(vArray, 2)
        If Len(vArray(i, j)) <> 0 Then
            dict.Add k, vArray(i, j)
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next
Next

Sheet1.Range("c1").Resize(dict.Count).Value = _
Application.Transpose(dict.items)

End Sub
```

This is **much faster** than using special cells (since VBA handles the work without consulting Excel) and you can use transpose as if it were paste, so I prefer this method.

As JFC has noted, using a dictionary object doesn't really seem to have a lot of benifits, the biggest reason is that it's easy to transpose the array plus you can transpose it horizontally as well, which is very fun.

```
Sheet1.Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(1, dict.Count + 2)).Value = _ 
Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(dict.items))
```

Comment: I like it! Does SpecialCells just iterate internally anyway, do you happen to know?  I always thought it used some kind of metadata that already existed.

Comment: Basically, "my only alternative to do it in a loop and compare cells as <> "" "

Comment: I don't know the actual implementation but I've recently did an exhaustive test of run times using it and discovered that the variant + len checks is still much faster.

Comment: If you want to avoid looping and checking for <> "", you can do a for each loop through the SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) group, but it will be slower than using the variant array and after much testing, it't surprisingly not that much faster to loop through special cells than all of them + checking for blanks. Guess special cells takes us power.

Comment: Added example how to do this without the variant array OR need to check for empty cell. Please note that you won't see a particular improvement by using special cells and you definitly won't get near the performance of the variant array.

Comment: +1 for interesting use of Dictionary, though I wouldn't really say that "without the variant array" is a selling point. You're using `For Each` exactly as in the two other answers, but replacing the native array with an external reference to the Scripting DLL. My sensei would ask: Why?

Comment: Maybe you can use this with a variant array (never tried), but you can transpose the array that dict.items spits out either verically or horizontally, which I find incredibly convenient. To do it horizontally, you can do something like: Sheet1.Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(1, dict.Count + 2)).Value = _
Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(dict.items))

Answer (score 1):

Since the Range object represents actual cells (`A1`,`A2`,`A3`,`A5` and `A8` in this case), I don't think you can compact in a 5-consecutive-cells Range without pasting it anywhere.

However, if you need to to loop on it, you don't need to use a comparison, using `For Each` will skip the blanks:

```
Set Rng = Range("A1:A8").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
Print Rng.count
 5 
For Each cell in Rng: Print cell: Next cell
Jon 
Jim 
Sally 
Jane 
Mary
```

It's probably not much, but it may help you depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Do you think the copy/paste does something like this internally?  I was also trying stuff with `SelectedRange`, but I don't think that was working either.

Comment: I guess it does. The `Range` does represent these five cells anyway, as evidenced by the `For Each` loop and the `Count` property. However the cells indices are 1,2,3,5 and 8. (`Print Rng(8)` give Mary). The other indices aren't exactly in the `Range`, but if you try to refer to them you'll get blanks. Since the `Range` is linked to specific cells of the sheet (and I don't think you can have it otherwise), there's no way to compact it to remove the holes, short of deleting A4, A6 and A7. I'm afraid I don't see any other thing that might help.